# Props not updated after action dispatched

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to implement Twitter authentication with React/Redux/Node.js. The back-end part is working fine, since the front-end is getting the right data.
The problem I'm facing right now is at the front-end. More specifically, when the token is received after the successful authentication, an action is dispatched, so that the `props` are updated as a consequence. However, this doesn't happen. Here is the code:

*Header.js*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import TwitterLogin from 'react-twitter-auth';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { loginSuccess, logout } from './redux/actions/actions';

import 'bulma/css/bulma.css';

class Header extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onSuccess = this.onSuccess.bind(this);
    this.onFailed = this.onFailed.bind(this);
  }

  onSuccess = (response) => {
    const token = response.headers.get('x-auth-token');
    response.json().then(user => {
      if (token) {
        this.props.loginSuccess(user, token);
      }
    });
  };

  onFailed = (error) => {
    alert(error);
  };

  logout = () => {
    this.props.logout();
  };

  render() {
    let content = this.props.isAuthenticated === true ?
      (
        <div>
          <div>
            <Link className="button is-primary" to="/profile">Profile</Link>
            <button onClick={this.logout} className="button" >
              Log out
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      ) :
      (
        <TwitterLogin 
          loginUrl="http://localhost:5000/api/auth/twitter"
          onFailure={this.onFailed} onSuccess={this.onSuccess}
          requestTokenUrl="http://localhost:5000/api/auth/twitter/reverse"
          className="button" />
      );


    return (
      <header className="navbar has-shadow is-spaced">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="navbar-brand">
            <h1 className="title is-4">
              <Link to="/" className="navbar-item">
                <strong>App</strong>
              </Link>
            </h1>
          </div>
          <div className="navbar-end">
            <div className="buttons">
              {content}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({token, user, isAuthenticated}) => ({token, user, isAuthenticated});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {loginSuccess,
  logout})(Header);
```

*actions.js*

```
export const loginSuccess = (user, token) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({type: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS', payload: {user, token}})
  }
}
```

*reducers.js*

```
const initialState = {
  token: null,
  user: null,
  isAuthenticated: false,
  error: false
};

export default (state=initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'LOGOUT':
      localStorage.removeItem('user');
      return initialState;
    case 'LOGIN_ERROR':
      return {
        ...state,
        error: true
      }
    case 'LOGIN_SUCCESS':
      return {
        token: action.payload.token,
        user: action.payload.user,
        isAuthenticated: true,
        error: false
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

*store.js*

```
import {applyMiddleware, createStore} from 'redux';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import reducer from './reducer';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware)(createStore);

export const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducer);
```

What am I missing here? Is there something missing in the *onSuccess* function? 
Thanks!

Comment: Hey, I looked through the code everything seems correct and it should work. Only thing which is suspicious for me is the way that you defined your action. If you are using redux-thunk then I am fine with it. If you are not using redux-thunk just return an object{type,payload} in your action it should fix the issue.

Comment: Hi. I've updated my question with the _store.js_ code. Is it the right way to use redux-thunk?

Comment: Thanks for the update could you please try this 
export const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue! I was declaring the `mapStateToProps` in the wrong way. 
The right code is the following:

*Header.js*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import TwitterLogin from 'react-twitter-auth';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { loginSuccess, logout } from './redux/actions/actions';

import 'bulma/css/bulma.css';

class Header extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onSuccess = this.onSuccess.bind(this);
    this.onFailed = this.onFailed.bind(this);
  }

  onSuccess = (response) => {
    const token = response.headers.get('x-auth-token');
    response.json().then(user => {
      if (token) {
        this.props.loginSuccess(user, token);
      }
    });
  };

  onFailed = (error) => {
    alert(error);
  };

  logout = () => {
    this.props.logout();
  };

  render() {
    let content = this.props.users.isAuthenticated === true ?
      (
        <div>
          <div>
            <Link className="button is-primary" to="/profile">Profile</Link>
            <button onClick={this.logout} className="button" >
              Log out
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      ) :
      (
        <TwitterLogin 
          loginUrl="http://localhost:5000/api/auth/twitter"
          onFailure={this.onFailed} onSuccess={this.onSuccess}
          requestTokenUrl="http://localhost:5000/api/auth/twitter/reverse"
          className="button" />
      );


    return (
      <header className="navbar has-shadow is-spaced">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="navbar-brand">
            <h1 className="title is-4">
              <Link to="/" className="navbar-item">
                <strong>App</strong>
              </Link>
            </h1>
          </div>
          <div className="navbar-end">
            <div className="buttons">
              {content}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({users}) => ({users});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {loginSuccess,
  logout})(Header);
```

Here is the code where I combine the reducers:

*reducer.js*

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import users from './reducers/users';
import polls from './reducers/polls';

export default combineReducers({
    users,
    polls
});
```

By using this code, I'm able to see the props updated after the action is dispatched. 
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Please try to replace

```
    case 'LOGIN_SUCCESS':
  return {
    token: action.payload.token,
    user: action.payload.user,
    isAuthenticated: true,
    error: false
  }
```

by:

```
    case 'LOGIN_SUCCESS':
  return {
    ...state,token: action.payload.token,
    user: action.payload.user,
    isAuthenticated: true,
    error: false
  }
```

Comment: That's not necessary because all the state properties are overwritten anyway.